# using scanf with a struct passed by reference

Tags: c, pointers, input, scanf

I am passing a struct info a function, and in that function I am using scanf() to assign input values to the inner variables of the struct.  The inner variable is an `unsigned int`.

When I use:
`scanf("%u",s->member)` or `scanf("%u",(*s).member)` I get a warning:

> windows.c:62:36: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int *' but the
>         argument has type 'unsigned int' [-Wformat]

And a seg fault when I run.

If I use `s.member` or `(&s).member` I get a compiler error.

Is there something I need to be doing different because I am trying to access a struct inner variable?

I know there are apparently issues with scanf() so some people say to use fgets(), is this an issue of scanf()?

Comment: Remember, there is no *pass-by-reference* in C, it is all *pass-by-value*. To simulate a *pass-by-reference*, you are simply passing the *address-of* an object *by-value* as the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I need to use

```
scanf("%u", &s->member);
```

Comment: Of course, you always have to use `&` with scanf arguments (except strings). It has nothing to do with how the struct was passed.